# How to calculate in RDD PYSPARK total sales price for each specific line

Tags: python, apache, pyspark, sum, rdd

I have a dataset like:

> 1|goldenrod lavender spring chocolate lace|Manufacturer#1|Brand#13|PROMO BURNISHED COPPER|7|JUMBO PKG|901.00|ly. slyly ironi|
>
> 2|blush thistle blue yellow saddle|Manufacturer#1|Brand#13|LARGE BRUSHED BRASS|1|LG CASE|902.00|lar accounts amo|
>
> 3|spring green yellow purple cornsilk|Manufacturer#4|Brand#42|STANDARD POLISHED BRASS|21|WRAP CASE|903.00|egular deposits hag|
>
> 4|cornflower chocolate smoke green pink|Manufacturer#3|Brand#34|SMALL PLATED BRASS|14|MED DRUM|904.00|p furiously r|

I want to calculate the total sales price for each brand.
For example Brand#13 (901,00+913,00= 1814,009).

Here is my Code:

```
    from operator import add
import operator
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import pyspark

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("part").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def Func(lines):
      
    lines = lines.split("|") 
    return  lines[2],lines[3]

def Funcc(lines):
      
    lines = lines.split("|") 
    return  lines[3],lines[7]



text = sc.textFile("part.tbl")
text1 = text.map(Func)
text2 = text.map(Funcc)

sort1 = text1.distinct().sortBy(lambda x:x[0], ascending=True).sortBy(lambda y:y[1], ascending = True)
sort2 = text2.sortBy(lambda x:x[0], ascending=True)

original_text = sort1.collect()
count_by_key = sort2.countByKey()
summe = sort2.reduceByKey(add).collect()


print("Manufacturer and Brands:")
for line in original_text:
    print(line)

print("Number of Items of each Brand")
print(count_by_key)
print(summe)
```

I am NOT allowed to use dataframes..
I tried it with:

```
summe = sort2.collect()
summe1 = sum(summe[1])
```

but the code doesnt work: ERROR:

summe1 = sum(summe[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

I have now the answer: U can use simple the function reduceByKey. :

```
preis = sort2.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()

print("Total sales price of each Brand")
print(preis)
```